# How to make alert dialog match theme color?

Tags: java, android

So in the app I am making, I have both a dark and light theme. The light theme works fine, but the alert dialogs I have still show the background the same as the light theme. Since it is dark, the text changes to light and the user can't see anything. Is there a certain attribute I need to change?

Here is the styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#E53935</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#C62828</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#E53935</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#1565C0</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
        <!-- Other attributes -->
    </style>

<style name="Dark" parent="@style/AppTheme" >
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/secondary_text_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@android:color/tertiary_text_dark</item>
    </style>
```

Here is what it shows up as:

[image: activity]

Answer (score 1):

Solved: You need to create your own xml like this:

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DarkAlertDialog</item>
```

With this being your custom dialog:

```
<style name="DarkAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="background">@color/background_material_dark</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parent AppCompat and then use colorPrimary and colorAccent properties (without an Android prefix) to theme things.

Right now the styles are coming from a dialog subtheme and not being affected by these style definitions.

Comment: the parent here is my app theme, which is the AppCompat, I will add it so you can see.

Comment: My apologies I didn't realize I had scrolled down on my phone. I only saw the Dark theme. I'd use the MaterialDialog library.